# Can an iOS app be available to public but on a limited basis?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

One of my clients needs an app that can be visible to anyone on the app store but not necessarily accessed by anyone? For example: It can be accessed by only those people who are attending a seminar or meeting.

How can we achieve this? Any idea or suggestions.

Is there a way to create this kind of app with restricted access?

Have you seen any app like this on Apple Store? if yes, please provide app name or link.

Will Apple approve this kind of application?

Comment: I don't know about apps with restrictions other than locality. But if you have the attendees email or phone number, you could upload the .ipa to diawi.com on a enterprise account and send them the link to install it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an app store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 1):

You can't put it in the app store **and** limit it to only certain people. If it's in the store, it can be downloaded by anyone who has access to the store. There are a couple of possibilities that might work, though:

- If you have (or can get) an enterprise license, you can distribute the app yourself outside of the app store. It won't be in the app store, but you can restrict access.
- Put the app in the app store but require login credentials to access some or all of the app's functionality. A common approach is that without logging in, people can see whatever is on the event's public web site. Attendee-only features require login. Of course this adds the complexity of managing logins. You would probably need to provide Apple with login credentials during app submission.